# Excluding some rows in Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

When I want to exclude some data row, I used to use:

```
entry.object.filter(name__startwith='Tom').exclude(name='foo')
```

I want to give exclude conditions like below. Is it possible?

```
entry.object.filter(name__startwith='Tom').exclude(name=['bar','foo'])
```

Could you give me some solutions?

Answer (score 6):

To check if `name` is included in a list, use `__in`:

```
entry.object.filter(name__startwith='Tom').exclude(name__in=['bar','foo'])
```

[Link to the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)